# iOS: Google Analytics sendEventWithCategory returns NO on iPad Sim

Tags: ios, events, google-analytics

I have a strange behavior, the following code fails (returns NO) in 'result' on iPad Sim 6.1 but succeeds (returns YES) on iPhone Sim 6.1, any idea why?

```
    id result = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GA_TRACKING_ID];
    BOOL result = [[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]
      sendEventWithCategory:category
      withAction:action
      withLabel:label withValue:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution: the tracker got closed by mistake sometimes beween the init and event